# Mysql group by query optimization with 400000+ records

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, optimization

I have two tables namely 
`t_productspecificprice` which has discounts in it
and `t_productcategory` which maps `productids` with `categoryids`

`t_productspecificprice` can have multiple discount added for one `productid` however discount added most recently is only relevent.

`t_productspecificprice` has somewhere around 450000 records and
`t_productcategory` has ~350000+ records.

I need the latest discount for each `productid` for a particular `categoryid`.

The below query just does not work, error 504 in phpmyadmin.

the query:

```
select 
    a_categoryid as 'Category Id',
    t_productcategory.a_productid as 'Product Ids', 
    t_productspecificprice.a_reduction, 
    t_productspecificprice.a_reductiontype, 
    t_productspecificprice.a_to  

from t_productcategory

left join t_productspecificprice on t_productspecificprice.a_productid = t_productcategory.a_productid

left join 

(SELECT max(a_productspecificpriceid) as a_productspecificpriceid FROM t_productspecificprice 
    GROUP by a_productid
    ) 
as discounts on discounts.a_productspecificpriceid = t_productspecificprice.a_productspecificpriceid

where a_categoryid = 4
```

the schema:

[image]
[image]'

Explain info:
[image]

Can somebody optimize it?

Comment: i suggest to show the table schema, other than saying much in text. for better understanding.

Comment: your schema not contain information about indexes

Comment: You got a 504 timeout, presumably because your query took too long.
Q: How long did you wait before the timeout occurred?  Q: What indexes do you have?  Q: Have you done a "Show Plan"?  Please read these articles: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html.  And please update your post with 1) Index info, and 2) Explain info.

Comment: add info about indexes

Comment: what's the point of the `discounts` left join? You're not selecting anything from the table and it's a `left join` so you're also not using it as a filter

Comment: so that, if there is no discount mapped to a productid the corresponding data comes as null

Comment: But you're not selecting any corresponding data. Also, you're assuming that the max price of one product can never be equal to an intermediate price of another product. This seems like an unrealistic assumption

Comment: i am not max ing price, i am max ing priceid

Comment: why do i have a downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague suggested this query, it works fine:

```
SELECT 
  s1.a_categoryid,
  p1.a_productspecificpriceid, 
  s1.a_productid,
  p1.a_reduction,
  p1.a_from,
  p1.a_to 
FROM t_productcategory s1 

LEFT JOIN t_productspecificprice p1 ON (s1.a_productid = p1.a_productid) 
LEFT JOIN t_productspecificprice p2 ON (p1.a_productid = p2.a_productid AND p1.a_productspecificpriceid < p2.a_productspecificpriceid) 

WHERE p2.a_productid IS NULL AND s1.a_categoryid = 4
```

Comment: Okay. This is a trick to do a NOT EXISTS without a NOT EXISTS clause. Only needed in a weak DBMS that isn't capable of dealing with NOT EXISTS well enough. I was told that such is no longer needed in MySQL. So either I was told wrongly or you are using an old version of MySQL. Anyway, I'm glad you found a way to solve your problem.

Comment: our Server version is 5.5.42-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Answer (score 1):

This quite challenging question.
I too have experience this before with data merely 200k rows.
My system crawl to a halt with a simple recapitulation using two table join. 
The condition is almost the same as your, but different table and data.

If you use the explain command before your query, the mysql engine will provide execution plan of your query. There you would find that the amount of data row the mysql engine must analyze is staggering. not simple 400k + 350k. 
Try the following command. just add explain before your previous query

```
explain your_query;
```

and

```
explain extended your_query;
```

Then, try to monitor disk i/o, cpu and memory used by mysql process during the execution of your query.
You then find what been bottle neck your sql.
for instance, a SATA Drive have a common performance of 20-40MB/s.
Try to see what your system can do.

This a domain known now as Big Data Analysis.
To properly analyze the result of such big join, i'm afraid there is no simple solution.

The main problem with this big data processing, the mysql engine simply out of memory when caching all the key used in the query. 
So when that happen, the mysql is swapping memory in and out of alocated memory to harddisk. Thus, add more processing required.

The solution will involved restructuring your table or modifying hardware or add some helper table.

1. Use helper recapitulation table. processing trough a big data row take amount of time. you might want to break down your query into several temporary table(s) and fill them with result from group. Then use a final query that join table(s).
   For instance, you could use a tmp_recap_discount to fill result from maximum discount.

   ```
   insert into tmp_recap_discount 
   SELECT 
     a_productid, 
     max(a_productspecificpriceid) as a_productspecificpriceid 
   FROM    
     t_productspecificprice 
   GROUP by a_productid
   ```

   Use a scheduler / job to run this query since this grouping will take alot of process and time, then run a simple join against this table. If the query also run against 400k of data, it is adviced to create a temporary table to hold the result. so queue  a list of sql job to fill temporary recap tables. create a mutex or flag to mark if the jobs have completed so the php app simply look into the final table. There is no simple way to maximize execution time against big data table. Even a simple select with where clause will take significant time. So, it is adviced to run slow query directly using native / desktop app or using mysql command. It is not recommended to execute such slow query using php, even if you maximize php execution time to several days. Nasty thing could happen.
2. install mariadb. 
   it is a drop in replacement for mysql. just uninstall mysql, but leave the data folder. Then install mariadb over the mysql installation. If you want to play it safe, dump the database, and have it restore in a clean mariadb installation. the performance different in my case is very significant. over 300% improvement in execution time. Without changing the query. The performance improvement is very much significant that i have upgrade all of my sistem database from mysql to mariadb.
   but be carefull tough, because some programmer often use nasty subqueries, the way mariadb handle subquery(s) is slight different than mysql.
   so the output of all application using mysql must be tested thoroughly.
3. play with your hardware. Optimize setting. It is recommended you upgrade to mariaDB first tough, then play with the hardware and setting since the improvement is there.

   a. optimize mysql setting. try to find these setting in your my.ini or my.cnf. These is the basic optimizing setting.

   ```
   #default will be 128M, but you can increase safely around a quarter of system memory. 
   #If you have 8Gb, then it is safe to assume 2048M for innodb buffer.
   #The setting can be increased, just make sure, the system memory     have the amount free memory requested. 
   #If not, it will be using memory swapping again, and the performance will bottleneck.
   innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G

   #it will force the mysql engine to save your table(s) into different file(s) instead using just one giant file to store. 
   #But if the previous setting is set to 0, you have to use a fresh mysql / mariadb install and restore the database for this setting to take effect.
   innodb_file_pertable = 1
   ```

   b. Maximize disk io. To maximize disk io, simply use faster drive configuration. it might by to upgrade to 15k RPM SAS, a SSD Drive, or RAID 0 of SATA Drives, SAS Drives or SSD Drives

   c. Use table partitioning. but this will require in depth analysis to maximize the performance gain. 
   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning.html

Answer (score 0):

Your query uses the following outer joins:

1. Outer join all product specific prices.
2. Outer join all latest product specific prices.

In other words:

1. If there are product specific prices join them all. (Else join a null record.)
2. If the product specific price happens to be the latest product specific price join its ID. (Else join a NULL ID.)

So no matter if is the latest price or not, you stay with all your records. (Well, this is what an outer join is supposed to do after all.)

You could re-write your query thus for instance, so as to left outer join latest product specific prices:

```
select 
  a_categoryid as 'Category Id',
  t_productcategory.a_productid as 'Product Ids', 
  t_productspecificprice.a_reduction, 
  t_productspecificprice.a_reductiontype, 
  t_productspecificprice.a_to  
from t_productcategory
left join t_productspecificprice 
  on t_productspecificprice.a_productid = t_productcategory.a_productid
  and a_productspecificpriceid in
  (
    select max(a_productspecificpriceid) 
    from t_productspecificprice 
    group by a_productid
  );
```

An alternative with NOT EXISTS which might also be worth a try:

```
select 
  a_categoryid as 'Category Id',
  t_productcategory.a_productid as 'Product Ids', 
  t_productspecificprice.a_reduction, 
  t_productspecificprice.a_reductiontype, 
  t_productspecificprice.a_to  
from t_productcategory
left join t_productspecificprice 
  on t_productspecificprice.a_productid = t_productcategory.a_productid
  and not exists
  (
    select *
    from t_productspecificprice newer
    where newer.a_productid = t_productspecificprice.a_productid
    and newer.a_productspecificpriceid > t_productspecificprice.a_productspecificpriceid
  );
```

Comment: same problem with the first query...am still waiting

Comment: @ShekharJoshi you should fix that particular problem by not using phpmyadmin and using the mysql cli instead.

Comment: Well, it may take quite some time to collect all last price records. The first query gets all last prices first and works on these, whereas the second query tries to find the latest price on the fly. I don't know which is more promising. Both may run a long time. If the evaluation just takes too long, you may want to consider to hold redundant data, i.e. have the price also in t_product and fill it with an insert trigger on t_productspecificprice. Thus you wouldn't have to access t_productspecificprice at all as long as you are not interested in the price history.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try this

```
SELECT 
    pc.a_categoryid AS 'Category Id',
    pc.a_productid AS 'Product Ids', 
    psp.a_reduction, 
    psp.a_reductiontype, 
    psp.a_to,
    discounts.max_price_id  
FROM t_productcategory AS pc
LEFT JOIN t_productspecificprice AS psp 
    ON (psp.a_productid = pc.a_productid)
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT a_productid, MAX(a_productspecificpriceid) AS max_price_id 
        FROM t_productspecificprice 
        GROUP BY a_productid
    ) AS discounts 
    ON discounts.max_price_id = psp.a_productspecificpriceid
WHERE pc.a_categoryid = 4
```

and add a composite key on `(a_productid, a_productspecificpriceid)` in `t_productspecificprice` table

Comment: although it took a very long time for results to get displayed but it says that query executed in 0.8490 seconds. I am also not seeing product ids where there is no discounts mapped, i need the corresponding data as null if no discounts are mapped.

Comment: answer updated. displaying - is certainly another "problem". see what @AD7six said